# Parameter substitution bad substitution error on macOS High Sierra

Tags: bash, macos

The `${parameter[^|^^|,|,,][pattern]}` parameter substitution is giving me a bad substitution error.

```
$ echo $greeting
hello world
$ echo "${greeting^}."
-bash: ${greeting^}.: bad substitution
```

I updated to the latest `bash` version and keep getting the error.

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0)
```

I've looked everywhere and the only suggestion I've found is making sure it's running `bash` 4.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

I'm running macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your default shell is *not* the `bash` shell (downloaded from `brew install bash`) that contains the `v4` which supports the parameter expansion syntax you are referring to.

On macOS `echo $BASH_VERSION` will tell you the version of the current shell. `bash --version` tells you the version of the first `bash` in your `$PATH`. So the way you were looking at the version was not telling you the version that you were running.

You need to add the recent version of `bash` to the file `/etc/shells` as the last line and use the command to set the shell as the default on `Terminal`

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash "$USER"
```

After this close and re-open the `Terminal` to make it effect. Without adding this default option in your `Terminal`, you could only use the recent `bash` only on scripts with interpreter she-bang set to `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`

See also this [Ask Different answer to - Update bash to version 4.0 on OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/292760/190121)